# Admob After Splash Screen

Tags: android, admob

Google changed admob using. Its allowing after splash screen interstial ad.
I write a code. Its working another app but a app. Its not working. 
Its my Activity splash. I am using for splash. Firstly opening splash then admob interstial. Its working another app but this app not working.

```
public class ActivitySplash extends Activity {
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx/xxxxx");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity

                // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener

                Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, MainActivity.class);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    startActivity(i);
                }


                // close this activity
                finish();

            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("C56E5F8DEC56E64E3997ED0856A63292")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SplashActivity is a really poor place to put an interstitial. It is very likely that the interstitial will never be received before your app has loaded.

Comment: ?? I don't know what rules you are referring to, but this behaviour has been there since Admob first starting serving Interstitials 3.5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Adding interstitial add after the splash screen is not recommended as it annoys users. but If you want to display add then:

> You have to add additional delay for add to load

when the ad is loaded, you can display it before launching the next activity.

bellow is working code(but this is not a good practice).

```js
        InterstitialAd ad;

        ad = new InterstitialAd(this);
        ad.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial));
        ad.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        ad.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(ad.isLoaded()) {
                    ad.show();
                }
                else{
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }, 4000);
```

As I have intentionally added the delay of 4 seconds (As a timestamp for the ad to load.).